# Transfer multiple records in list in class

Tags: c#, list, class

I want to pass class to front angular app from backend c#.

for that I made special class where I pass some params. PLease take a look at the last one.

There is seperate table in DB which stores pics. And I want to pass list of pictures with other data. for that in transfer class I tried to declare list of piclass.

```
public List<PicsClass> PicsClass{ get; set; }
```

This gave me error and after some googling I've found this

```
public List<Type> PicsClass{ get; set; }
```

So here are my transfer and pic classes.

```
 public class TransferClass
    {
        public int TransferClassID { get; set; }
        public string param1{ get; set; }
        public int param2{ get; set; }

        public List<Type> PicsClass{ get; set; }
    }

public class PicsClass
{
    public int PicsClassID{ get; set; }
    public int param1ID { get; set; }
    public int param2ID{ get; set; }
}
```

Now in controller I query DB for pics and put them into list of TransferClass object

```
    List<PicsClass> Images = _context.PicsClasses.Where(u => u.param2ID== param2ID).ToList();

        TransferClass.Images = Images;
```

And get error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   system.coolection.......Entities.PicsClass to 
>   system.coolections.generic.list

How can I fix this?

Comment: My problem is that I want to put in TransferClass List of type PicsClass

Comment: and what is wrong with `public List<PicsClass> PicsClass{ get; set; }` in `TransferClass` ? ... or  `List<int>` and select only `PicsClassID` if rest props are irrevelant for the cllient?

Comment: 'MediaTypeNames.PicsClass': static types cannot cannot be used as type arguments

Comment: Move `PicsClass` out of `MediaTypeNames`.

Comment: Wait a minute! What is this `List<Type>`? Don't you want `List<PicsClass>` instead?

Comment: I want but I cannot. If I write List<PicsClass> I get 'MediaTypeNames.PicsClass': static types cannot cannot be used as type arguments

Comment: you may also use `IEnumerable<object> PicsClass`  (or even `object PicsClass` as json serializer works fine with them) as long as you don't wana assign `IEnumerable<T>` where  `T` is not reference type

Comment: So what's better to write in TransferClass ????

Comment: `List<PicsClass>` is good, but you have to move `PicsClass` out of `MediaTypeNames`.

Comment: I don't correctly understand where is MediaTypeNames can you excuse me and explain that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a wrong type in your PicsClass property, it should be like this:

```
public class TransferClass
{
    public int TransferClassID { get; set; }
    public string param1{ get; set; }
    public int param2{ get; set; }
    public List<PicsClass> PicsClass{ get; set; }
}

public class PicsClass
{
    public int PicsClassID{ get; set; }
    public int param1ID { get; set; }
    public int param2ID{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 'MediaTypeNames.PicsClass': static types cannot cannot be used as type arguments